# Problem with C# ref when used in parent class

Tags: c#, reference, ref

I have the abstract class

```
  public abstract class BaseType
  {
    public BaseType(int offset)
    {
      TestRef(ref offset);
    }

    protected abstract void TestRef(ref int offset);
  }
```

and a derived type,

```
  public class DerivedType : BaseType 
  {
    public DerivedType(int offset) : base(offset)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"ctor: increasing offset: {++offset}");
    }
    
    protected override void TestRef(ref int offset)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"TestRef: increasing offset: {++offset}");
    }
  }
```

and a main where I instantiate a derived type:

```
  public static void Main()
  {
    var dt = new DerivedType(0);
  }
```

I assumed that since `TestRef` takes a reference to the `offset` that I would have seen the change `TestRef` addition. In other words I would have expected the output bellow,

```
TestRef: increasing offset: 1
ctor: increasing offset: 2
```

but I'm getting

```
TestRef: increasing offset: 1
ctor: increasing offset: 1
```

What I've done wrong here?

Comment: TestRef gets a reference, but the call to base(offset) is by value.

Comment: Good observation, thanks @TobiasKildetoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, to achieve the behaviour you want you need to consistently pass the integer by reference in all calls, as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseType
{
    public BaseType(ref int offset)
    {
        TestRef(ref offset);
    }

    protected abstract void TestRef(ref int offset);
}

public class DerivedType : BaseType
{
    public DerivedType(ref int offset) : base(ref offset)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ctor: increasing offset: {++offset}");
    }

    protected override void TestRef(ref int offset)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"TestRef: increasing offset: {++offset}");
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var dt = new DerivedType(ref 0);
}
```

Comment: As an added bonus: you don't need define ```DerivedType```'s ctor with ```ref``` to ```offset``` if you do not want the passed-in variable's value to change.

Answer (score -2):

The constructor argument which is passed to the base class via base(offset)  is passed by value to the base class and not by reference.
You can’t pass a constructor argument by reference.

Comment: Who says that I can't pass a constructor argument by reference if I have defined it as such?

Comment: `
public BaseType(
  byte[] body,
  ref int offset)
{
  
}
`